# Include sub-folder options is coming as unchecked in VS 2010 Find and replace window

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my solution if do ctrl + shift + F, Find and replace window opens but in that include sub-folder option is coming as unchecked and it is disabled so I cant check it back. How to check that check box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change "Look in:" to an actual folder (c:\dev\ for example) instead of Current Solution or any of the other predefined choices it is editable.